# Como faço para setar um valor no EditText caso vazio?

Tags: android

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewByid(R.id.edit); //estabeleço o conexão

if(edit.getText().toString().isEmpty()){ // verificando se a edit esta vazia

String num = "6"; // Ou use um int, não vejo necessidade de ser um double

edit.setText(num); //inserindo valor na edit
}
```

//código acima funciona

//este abaixo não

//método que chama pela class
public class Temperatura  {

```
public double getFaRetorneCels(double cel){
    return  ((cel*9)/5)+32;
}

public double getCelRetorneFa(double fah){
    return ((fah-32)*5/9);
}
```

}

// código do botão

public void convert(View view){
        EditText edtcel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtCel);
        EditText edtfa = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ediFa);

```
    Temperatura t = new Temperatura();

     double c = Double.parseDouble(edtcel.getText().toString());
     double f = Double.parseDouble(edtfa.getText().toString());

    if(edtcel.getText().toString().isEmpty() && edtfa.getText().toString().isEmpty() ){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Pelo menos um campo deve ser preenchido!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(edtcel.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

        edtcel.setText(String.valueOf(t.getCelRetorneFa(f)));

    }else  if (edtfa.toString().isEmpty()){

        edtfa.setText(String.valueOf(t.getFaRetorneCels(c)));


    }
```

Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim:

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewByid(R.id.edit); //estabeleço o conexão

if(edit.getText().toString().isEmpty()){ // verificando se a edit esta vazia

String num = "6"; // Ou use um int, não vejo necessidade de ser um double

edit.setText(num); //inserindo valor na edit
}
```

Comment: Consegui achar a solução, Obrigado dele ajuda @Woton Sampaio o problema estava na double porque eu estava atribuindo o valor dela baseando pelo Edit ignorando que um dos Edit fosse vir vazio, bastou colocar a double dentro da condição dos if e deu certo rodou normal sem problemas agradeço pela ajuda.